# How to replicate the function in Bootstrap's row and col?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Would like to arrange my code side by side like Bootstrap's col but do not wish to download the whole Bootstrap file just to use the col.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you even tried to do this yet?

Comment: there are various solutions for this. display:flex;display:table;float:left;float;right;display:inline-block;display:inline it all depends on what you really want to achieve. //// my advice is to use bootstrap , it's also responsive and more flexible than any other solutions

Comment: Resolved in using display: flex; to arrange elements side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

On the Bootstrap 3 site, there is a "Customize" option on the navbar which will allow you to select the components you require.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in using display: flex; to arrange elements side-by-side.

```
 #html
 <form id='text_form' class='container'>
   <div class='item1'></div>
   <div class='item2'></div>
 </form>

#css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .item1 {
    width: 60%;
  }

  .item2 { 
    width: 40%; 
  }
}
```